# nodejs jsonwebtoken verify error with some tokens

Tags: node.js, jwt, json-web-token

I've got a java service that generates json web tokens signed with RS256.
Then a service in node verifies the tokens with the public key using the jsonwebtoken module.

The problem is that some tokens work and some do not. According to jwt.io every token is correct.

This an example code with a working one and a failing one

```
var sanitize = function(data){
  return data.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=*$/g, '')
}
var jwtGood = sanitize("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InBlbGF5by11c2VybmFtZTMiLCJlbWFpbCI6InBlbGF5by5yYW1vbisxMkBjbG91ZGRpc3RyaWN0LmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJpZCI6InVhb2V1YW9lb2FldTMiLCJpYXQiOjE0NTYxNDkwMjR9.tmvgtpuyuUiql2aYeR38kGTeQUwyb7XZr6Df2iv09_nxDn4HltHZm7Fvbj07ZQ5Hh_DmvlqZHz7EVSV6mERdjkohxf8tt9-J6NW_ftnUurCfLIzCcqEJ4xlKOzIgGsGrRd4ZUhw2hs4ZNTIscUb37csvKV-jPdSdQ-TxzuWZen4QnEUGvyg0VhdlU90TGZmpzobfpbHMQ3C0qhGRDMjghgej8zjWHbRDFRIGtAHLDbYVMiQRdI_GODIco2uSVh0_9PATSeRhFosHf3P3R4ohyBMrn9rxmBW4bQyFEMXWtsl4_PrKsdsaTtKjVQ2YuL5GjKQJqkWp6vx2vIxRabHz7w==");
var jwtBad  = sanitize("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InBlbGF5by11c2VybmFtZSIsImVtYWlsIjpudWxsLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwiaWQiOm51bGwsImlhdCI6MTQ1NjMwMTUwN30=.X_vogPRHoE-ws2DxB8Q3wlm5JCQdOvuedhUC-1BlGa9qPdg5nmAGLoLuuGmQZ9r2yUD45OqKQ8_PVd05b0gQBhlIIWtQsXMSWypN6o43noZqMG6aM-GeAK-edDg2C7zw0yGQDD1BNLKBeWc8lNPzJAqQV0il_lg6bytIeN2LMAgxj78RZro3snkXN4woe6afCefW78z3KiOIQ2qI3pcA6Kf4j9NErHwfe9BP2dnV3mXTOZ8SIds_C9JWb7nt9o6Z4oCpskmXxhRCpP4ptTS0krGKfzfhYMKj2e7uOwS1pV4MdpQBeLlhZaGn3pmG5kwl3ZzEeIANfE7N8a9LofmFsQ==");

var jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');

var pubKey = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');

console.log(jwtGood);
jsonwebtoken.verify(jwtGood, pubKey,{ algorithms: ['RS256'] },function(err, decoded){
  console.log(err,decoded);
});

console.log(jwtBad);
jsonwebtoken.verify(jwtBad, pubKey,{ algorithms: ['RS256'] },function(err, decoded){
  console.log(err,decoded);
});
```

The main difference just by looking at them is the "=" character at the end of the encoded payload. Working one payload ends in "MjR9." and failing one in "wN30=."

Removed the "=" by hand (as i did with the ending ones) but, according to jwt.io, without it the token is not verified.

Tried some more sanitize functions but they didn't work.

My guess is that there is a base64 encoding issue here but I can't find it.

Comment: Why are you sanitizing them?  I'm using the jwt-simple node module, and I just put the encoded token (without any modification) into a cookie, and when it comes back I take the cookie contents and straight decode it.  Works great.

Comment: Needed to remove the ending "==". Tokens did not verify when left it. Noticed by creating tokens in jwt.io, their tokens did not contain the ending "==" which comes from the base64 encoding to fill the last 4 char block. Also the sanitize changes some chars for the token to be url encoded. The first 2 replace can be deleted, does not affect the result as there are no "+" or "/" in the example tokens.

Comment: Switched to jwt-simple and works like a charm but I do not like the try catch code it enforces. I'm leaving this open while someone comes with a "real" solution.